# How to fix UNIQUE constraint failed: users_profile.user_id?

Tags: python, django

How to fix UNIQUE constraint failed: users_profile.user_id?
already have a created profile

views.py

```
class EditProfile(CreateView):
    model = Profile
    context_object_name = 'profile'
    template_name = 'users/profile_edit.html'

    fields = ['avatar', 'name', 'description']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:profile')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

urls.py

```
path('<slug:slug>/edit/', EditProfile.as_view(), name='profile_edit'),
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/avatars/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user)
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `CreateView` to Edit existing object. To Edit profile you should use `UpdateView`, because `CreateView` is trying to create NEW `Profile` object with `request.user` object, that already has got corresponding `Profile` object.